# Annotate a Google Slides Presentation using touchpad / pen

Tags: google-docs, google-slides, annotations

I am an educator and I use Google slides for my courses. I would like to be able to draw-on/annotate my slides with a touch device (iPad, Android tablet, etc) during a presentation.

I realize that if I first converted my slides to a PDF, I could probably find an app that would let me do this, but I want to be able to do this *during the actual presentation mode* of a Google slide document.

Does Google docs let you do this? Alternatively, is there a plugin or third-party app for this?

Comment: I ended up using Doceri to be able to annotate screenshots of slides during class.

Comment: PowerPoint has enabled this for quite some time. I download my Google slides as PPTX files and present them in PowerPoint. Sad that so much time goes into silly editing features and educationally useful features proven to help retain information are ignored.

Answer (score 4):

When you present a Google Slide on the web, a task bar appears on the bottom right of the presentation (**NOTE:** Not in the presenter view window but on the actual slide window). There is the option `Pointer` which you can to point at stuff (obviously) but you cannot mark it up. Google is considering to add this feature but they haven't launched it yet.
Alternatively, there is a free iPad app called `Notability` which allows you to ink on presentations. This app is available in the App Store.
**BTW:** You have to convert your file to PDF in order to open it in this app.
I hope this helped you answer your question.

Comment: Do you have a link to the feature tracker?